# How to create type when using createRef for Animated.View in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, react-native

When creating a ref in a React Native component, Typescript complains about it if you don't provide the right type.

```
image = React.createRef();

state = {
    x: new Animated.Value(0),
    y: new Animated.Value(0),
};

render() {
    const {x, y} = this.state;
    const imageStyle = {left: x, top: y};

    return (
        <Animated.View
            ref={this.image} // I got warning message here
            {...this.responder}
            style={[styles.draggable, imageStyle]}>
            {this.props.children}
        </Animated.View>
    )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    draggable: {
    position: 'absolute',
    height: itemWidth,
    width: itemWidth,
    },  
});
```

I got this warning

> Type '{ children: ReactNode; style: ({ left: Value; top: Value; } | {
>   position: "absolute"; height: number; width: number; })[]; current:
>   unknown; ref: RefObject; }' is not assignable to type
>   'IntrinsicAttributes & AnimatedProps & { children?:
>   ReactNode; }'.   Property 'ref' does not exist on type
>   'IntrinsicAttributes & AnimatedProps & { children?:
>   ReactNode; }'

`createRef` line needs to be something like 
`image = React.createRef<some_type>();`
But I don't know how to create this `some_type`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating `@types/react-native` version solved the problem.

```
"@types/react-native": "^0.61.15", -> "@types/react-native": "^0.63.37",
```